# Accessing the server response when an error occurs in my saga request

Tags: redux, request, axios, redux-saga, http-error

I'm using the library `redux-saga-requests` for network communication and high level state management. Following the guidance from [the documentation](https://github.com/klis87/redux-saga-requests#interceptors-arrow_up), I've set up a global error handler to display a notification in case the server request times out or the user has connection troubles.

However, when I get a server error (500 for example), I can't access the response in my action. The server response is just not there.

Is there a way to access this object while still staying within the confines and rules of `redux-saga`?

Here's the initial store setup - note that `onErrorSaga` doesn't give me the network response, so I might as well go with the default behaviour - sending a suffixed `_ERROR` action that can be caught by my reducer:

```js
function* onErrorSaga(error, action) {
    console.log('error?', error)
    console.log('action?', action)

    // None of these contain the server response, 
    // just the error message and stack thrown by the client.

    yield { error }
}

function* rootSaga(axiosInstance) {
    yield createRequestInstance({
        driver: {
            default: createAxiosDriver(axiosInstance),
        },
        onError: onErrorSaga,
    })
    yield watchRequests()
}

const configureStore = initialState => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
    const middlewares = [thunkMiddleware, requestsPromiseMiddleware({ auto: true }), sagaMiddleware, trackingMiddleware]
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)))

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, axiosInstance)

    return store
}

export const configureStoreAsync = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const store = configureStore()
        store
            .dispatch(fetchAppInitialization())
            .then(result => resolve(store))
            .catch(e => reject(store))
    })
}
```

Here's how I'm currently handling errors in my state (which is then displayed by a notification component):

```js
import { CLOSE_NOTIFICATION } from '../actions/actions.notification'

export default (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type.endsWith('_ERROR')) {
        return {
            type: 'warning',
            title: action.error.message,
            message: `${action.error.stack.substring(0, 200)}...`,
            open: true,
            timestamp: new Date(),
        }
    }
    switch (action.type) {
        case CLOSE_NOTIFICATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                open: false,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was way easier than I thought. The `action` object does in fact contain the server response.

The path to the response is:

`action.error.response.data`